# Strange iOS app crashes on simulator

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, simulator, codesign

I have a strange crash.

```
Process:               MyApp [91555]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3EDD7C49-65E2-4046-8BEE-0AC829A2A276/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7667EA2E-A89B-44E8-8C14-828700B482E1/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:            MyApp
Version:               6.7 (6.7.0.3709)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd_sim [11615]
Responsible:           MyApp [91555]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-03-04 18:29:43.848 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.3 (16D32)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        74452B06-5487-4AB3-CA87-6DE166EFD550

Time Awake Since Boot: 790000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000032, 0x00000001013a9018
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x2

kernel messages:

VM Regions Near 0x1013a9018:
--> __TEXT                 00000001013a9000-0000000113ce1000 [297.2M] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3EDD7C49-65E2-4046-8BEE-0AC829A2A276/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7667EA2E-A89B-44E8-8C14-828700B482E1/MyApp.app/MyApp
    __DATA                 0000000113ce1000-0000000115cef000 [ 32.1M] rw-/rwx SM=COW  /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3EDD7C49-65E2-4046-8BEE-0AC829A2A276/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7667EA2E-A89B-44E8-8C14-828700B482E1/MyApp.app/MyApp

Application Specific Information:
CoreSimulator 338.16 - Device: iPhone 7 - Runtime: iOS 10.2 (14C89) - DeviceType: iPhone 7

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   dyld_sim                        0x000000011cea69dc ImageLoaderMachO::usesTwoLevelNameSpace() const + 8
1   dyld_sim                        0x000000011ceac85b ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::doBindFastLazySymbol(unsigned int, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, void (*)(), void (*)()) + 43
2   dyld_sim                        0x000000011ce9abb9 dyld::fastBindLazySymbol(ImageLoader**, unsigned long) + 90
3   libdyld.dylib                   0x000000012b2b7516 dyld_stub_binder + 282
4   ???                             0x0000000113ce1008 0 + 4627238920
5   MyApp                           0x000000010ecca652 __54-[SpriteDataManager loadAnimFrames:savePath:callback:]_block_invoke_2 + 210
6   libclang_rt.asan_iossim_dynamic.dylib   0x000000012827b334 __wrap_dispatch_async_block_invoke + 260
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000012b24f808 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000012b27112e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000012b2584fb _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1054
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000121e88e49 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000121e4e37d __CFRunLoopRun + 2205
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000121e4d884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
13  com.apple.GraphicsServices      0x000000012a484a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
14  com.apple.UIKit                 0x000000012408ec68 UIApplicationMain + 159
15  MyApp                           0x0000000104c4f326 main + 1238
16  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000012b2ba68d start + 1
```

Since apps on simulator don't need code signing at all, why the Exception Type says EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code Signature Invalid)? Could anyone explain  what this kind of crash is and how it happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Try going into "Edit Scheme" and unchecking all of the tests from "Build" clean your app And run it again.
2. Go to `TARGETS`> `Tests` make sure you signin or if its  `ad hoc` signed in the Test Target then set up a profile for the Test target or click `Automatically Signing`

Comment: It seems work. However, I want to know the internal details.

Comment: There are several reason for that but one of might you have  running the project on another machine with Sierra it gave you an Error. please mark my answer as accepted.